# Shortcut to finding $E(XY)$

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

The question says "Find $E(Y|X)$ and hence evaluate $E(Y)$ and $E(XY)$"

The joint pdf is $$f_{X,Y}(x,y)=\begin{cases} 8xy, & \text{ for } 0< y< x < 1, \\0, & \text{ elsewhere } \end{cases}$$ I found $E(X)=4/5$ in an earlier part, $E(Y\mid X)= 2x/3$ and $$E(Y)= \int E(Y|X)\cdot f_X(x) dx =\frac{8}{15}$$

Is there a way to find $E(XY)$ without integrating directly from the pdf like $$\iint xy\cdot f_{X,Y}(x,y) dx dy$$

Is there a shorter way, kind of like what I did when I found $E(Y)$? The question says "hence evaluate $E(XY)$", so I'm guessing there is some sort of shortcut.

Comment: Your double integral suggestion is correct. But it seems the exercise does nt want you to do it that way.

Comment: You should read http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation to see how to use MathJax on this site to improve readability.

Comment: I believe this was asked recently. Were you the OP?

Comment: No I was not. This is my first stats question on this site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already have an expression for $\mathsf E[Y\mid X]$ and presumably $f_X(x)$ then:

$$\begin{align}
\mathsf E[XY] & = \mathsf E[\mathsf E[XY\mid X] & \text{by the Law of Iterated Expectation.}
\\& = \mathsf E[X\cdot\mathsf E[Y\mid X]] & \text{ as $X$ is constant measured wrt $X$.}
\\ & = \int x \cdot\mathsf E[Y\mid X=x]\cdot f_X(x)\operatorname d x & \text{by definition: }\mathsf E[g(X)]=\int g(x)f_X(x)\operatorname d x
\end{align}$$

Comment: Could you explain a bit about how the first line works? Does this mean E[Y|X]=Y ?

Comment: No, @user124249 , it is the **Law of Iterated Expectation**.  Sometimes called the *Law of Total Expectation*.  $\mathsf E(g(X,Y)) = \mathsf E\bigl(\mathsf E(g(X,Y)\mid X)\bigr)$

Comment: It's perfectly clear to me now after the edits.